# Foundation and React Sass integration

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, sass, zurb-foundation, styling

I created a React app using the `create-react-app` package. I've including the minified css allowing me to use Foundations class system.

Now I want to customize the styles provided by Foundation.

I see there is a foundation folder within the node modules that contains the necessary `_settings.scss`, `_gloabl.scss`, and `foundation.scss` files, but I don't think I should be pulling those files out and dropping them in my src folder.

How can I set up my folder structure up with a React app that utilizes Foundations Sass library giving me customization abilities?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would want to copy that _settings.scss file into your sass architecture. Once copied over, edit it how you would please.

Then import that settings file before the foundation components in your main compilation file so that they will use those settings. This is an example of some code I've written in the past.

```
// Reset css.
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/normalize";

// This is the file you created for foundation settings. 
// Now all the imported foundation components will use these settings.
@import "./base/settings";

// Make sure the charset is set appropriately
@charset "UTF-8";

// Behold, here are all the Foundation components.
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/grid";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/accordion";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/alert-boxes";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/block-grid";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/buttons";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/clearing";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/dropdown";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/dropdown-buttons";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/forms";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/inline-lists";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/labels";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/pagination";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/progress-bars";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/range-slider";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/reveal";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/split-buttons";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/switches";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/tables";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/tooltips";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/type";
@import "../../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/visibility";
```

Comment: Am I just copying over the _settings.scss file and leaving the other files within the node_modules folder?

Comment: yea. just make sure you import your settings file before the components like above.